# How do I convert RGB into HSV in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, rgb, color-space, hsv

I want to set the background color of a label using HSV instead of RGB.  How do I implement this into code?

Code:

```
//.m file

#import "IBAppDelegate.h"

@implementation IBAppDelegate


@synthesize label;

{
self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f
                                             green:0.8f
                                              blue:0.0f
                                             alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following convenience constructor of the `UIColor` object:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHue:(CGFloat)hue saturation:(CGFloat)saturation brightness:(CGFloat)brightness alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

Comment: RGB -> HSV requires some custom code, but HSV -> RGB is pretty easy. You're in luck!

Comment: Thanks!  It didn't know it would be so easy.  That specific code actually gave me some syntax errors.  It worked out better as:

  [UIColor colorWithHue:(CGFloat) saturation:(CGFloat) brightness:(CGFloat) alpha:(CGFloat)]

Comment: Evelyn: That's because what arul gave you is the method's prototype, not a message expression. It's not supposed to be pasted into a method body.