# Is there function to convert UIColor to Hue Saturation Brightness?

Tags: ios, uicolor, hsb

i can set uicolor with RGB values:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:0.53 green:0.37 blue:0.11 alpha:1.00];
```

i can set uicolor with hsb values:

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:0.10 saturation:0.16 brightness:0.13 alpha:1.00];
```

i also could convert it back to RGB:

```
CGFloat* colors = CGColorGetComponents(Color1.CGColor);
```

But how i can get HSB from uicolor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142427/uicolor-conversion-from-rgb-to-hsv-set-brightness-to-uicolor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017553/converting-from-rgb-to-hsl-with-objective-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050874/how-do-i-convert-rgb-into-hsv-in-cocoa-touch

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the `UIColor` method:
`getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:`

From the Apple docs:
"Returns the components that make up the color in the HSB color space."

```
- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat *)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha
```

Example:

```
UIColor *testColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.53 green:0.37 blue:0.11 alpha:1.00];

CGFloat hue;
CGFloat saturation;
CGFloat brightness;
CGFloat alpha;
BOOL success = [testColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
NSLog(@"success: %i hue: %0.2f, saturation: %0.2f, brightness: %0.2f, alpha: %0.2f", success, hue, saturation, brightness, alpha);
```

NSLog output:

> success: 1 hue: 0.10, saturation: 0.79, brightness: 0.53, alpha: 1.00

Here is a corrected version of the method provided by @WhiteTiger:

```
// Test values
CGFloat red = 0.53;
CGFloat green = 0.37;
CGFloat blue = 0.11;

CGFloat hue = 0;
CGFloat saturation = 0;
CGFloat brightness = 0;

CGFloat minRGB = MIN(red, MIN(green,blue));
CGFloat maxRGB = MAX(red, MAX(green,blue));

if (minRGB==maxRGB) {
    hue = 0;
    saturation = 0;
    brightness = minRGB;
} else {
    CGFloat d = (red==minRGB) ? green-blue : ((blue==minRGB) ? red-green : blue-red);
    CGFloat h = (red==minRGB) ? 3 : ((blue==minRGB) ? 1 : 5);
    hue = (h - d/(maxRGB - minRGB)) / 6.0;
    saturation = (maxRGB - minRGB)/maxRGB;
    brightness = maxRGB;
}
NSLog(@"hue: %0.2f, saturation: %0.2f, value: %0.2f", hue, saturation, brightness);
```

NSLog output:

> hue: 0.10, saturation: 0.79, value: 0.53

Comment: but this feature is bootable only by 5.0

Comment: Over 75% of iOS users are on 5.0 now and a higher percentage of users who buy and/or update apps. If < 5.0 is a requirement please update your question.

Comment: you know, but there are cases, such as business where there is' an obligation to remain compatible with previous versions.

Comment: Your varient works perfectly, now im working on iOS 5 device, as i understood it wouldnt work on previos versions? if i need iOS do i have to use WhiteTiger's varient?

Comment: The WhiteTiger variant works on any iOS version, the Apple getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: variant works on iOS 5+. I added the WhiteTiger variant to my answer only because the early WhiteTiger versions had errors, now corrected.

Comment: @zaph, thanks for the great answer, but can I change the HSB values based on UISlider changes?

Comment: You can possibly find an Xcode extension, [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io) is an Xcode extension manager.

Answer (score 28):

Here is a nice way of using Swift features (extensions, computed properties and tuples) to do the same thing in just a few lines of code.

```
extension UIColor {
  var hsba: (h: CGFloat, s: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
    var hsba: (h: CGFloat, s: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.getHue(&(hsba.h), saturation: &(hsba.s), brightness: &(hsba.b), alpha: &(hsba.a))
    return hsba
  }
}
```

**Swift 3.2 / 4 minor update**

Swift 3.2 / 4 enforced a new warning triggered with the previous code because you were modifying the `hsba` variable several times within the same call to `getHue`

> Simultaneous accesses to parameter 'hsba', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable.

```
extension UIColor {
    var hsba: (h: CGFloat, s: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
        var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
        self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
        return (h: h, s: s, b: b, a: a)
    }
}
```

Comment: usage: 
    self.inputUIImage?.getColors({ (colors) in
    let hue = colors.primaryColor.hsba.h
    self.hueFilter?.hue = hue
    })

Comment: Thanks, packaging this code as an extension with tuple return is quite nice and useful

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use this (Swift 3.1)?

Answer (score 4):

Beware that it is a draft, but you can try this code, if you're lower to version 5.0

```
...
CGFloat computedH = 0;
CGFloat computedS = 0;
CGFloat computedV = 0;

CGFloat minRGB = MIN(r, MIN(g,b));
CGFloat maxRGB = MAX(r, MAX(g,b));

if (minRGB==maxRGB) {
   computedH = 0;
   computedS = 0;
   computedV = minRGB;
} else {
   double d = (r==minRGB) ? g-b : ((b==minRGB) ? r-g : b-r);
   double h = (r==minRGB) ? 3 : ((b==minRGB) ? 1 : 5);
   computedH = (60*(h - d/(maxRGB - minRGB))) / 360.;
   computedS = ((maxRGB - minRGB)/maxRGB);
   computedV = maxRGB;
}
...
```

Comment: Comments: THe line `r=r/255.; g=g/255.; b=b/255.;` is unneeded if the values are already `CGFloat`s. The final `computedV` needs to be divided by 360.0 to obtain a value in the interval 0.0 to 1.0. The `double` types might be better as `CGFloat`.

Comment: I corrected your conversion routine and added it to my answer with a test case.

Comment: There are to many divisions by 360, `computedS` and `computedV` are incorrect. Only hue needs to be divided by 360 because it is an angle.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following segment of code and you are done for good with rgba, hsba conversion.

```
extension UIColor {

/**
 Decomposes UIColor to its RGBA components
 */
var rgbColor: RGBColor {
    get {
        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        return RGBColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
}

/**
 Decomposes UIColor to its HSBA components
 */
var hsbColor: HSBColor {
    var h: CGFloat = 0, s: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
    self.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
    return HSBColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: b, alpha: a)
}

/**
 Holds the CGFloat values of HSBA components of a color
 */
public struct HSBColor {
    var hue: CGFloat
    var saturation: CGFloat
    var brightness: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    var uiColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
        }
    }
}

/**
 Holds the CGFloat values of RGBA components of a color
 */
public struct RGBColor {
    var red: CGFloat
    var green: CGFloat
    var blue: CGFloat
    var alpha: CGFloat

    var uiColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
        }
    }
}
}
```