# How can I modify a UIColor's hue, brightness and saturation?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uikit, uicolor

Lets say I have a UIColor

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
```

Now I want to modify the saturation/hue/brigthness, how do I do that?
I did read the documentation but i'm still really confused

I want to modify the UIColor I made ([UIColor redColor]) not initiate a new color with some preferences. How do I modify it retaining the original. I do know about the`colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` method, I need to update an existing color's properties, keeping the red color.

Comment: You can use CoreImage framework. That will help you a lot.

Comment: Look into this posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071756/is-there-function-to-convert-uicolor-to-hue-saturation-brightness

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call `getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` on your color, then adjust the values, then create a new color with your adjusted components using `+[UIColor colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:]`

```
CGFloat hue, saturation, brightness, alpha ;
BOOL ok = [ <color> getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha ] ;
if ( !ok ) { 
    // handle error 
}
// ... adjust components..

UIColor * newColor = [ UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:alpha ] ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it worked! I'l just accept it in a min (Stackoverflow says i have to wait)

Comment: This works, however it doesn't meet your requirement that it be the same color object. But what you want isn't possible. UIColor is immutable--so you will always have to create a new color object.

Comment: @nielsbot I like your concise use of BOOL to kill 2 birds with one stone, so to speak. Excellent answer...

Answer (score 17):

Here is swift `UIColor` extension you might find useful:

```
extension UIColor {

    func modified(withAdditionalHue hue: CGFloat, additionalSaturation: CGFloat, additionalBrightness: CGFloat) -> UIColor {

        var currentHue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentSaturation: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentBrigthness: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        if self.getHue(&currentHue, saturation: &currentSaturation, brightness: &currentBrigthness, alpha: &currentAlpha){
            return UIColor(hue: currentHue + hue,
                           saturation: currentSaturation + additionalSaturation,
                           brightness: currentBrigthness + additionalBrightness,
                           alpha: currentAlpha)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's **quite a hassle** to change any of the `hsba` or `rgba` values of a UIColor **by default**. Using **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)** (install it via Carthage) makes your life **a lot easier**:

```
import HandyUIKit  

// each line creates a new UIColor object with the new value
color.change(.hue,        to: 0.1)
color.change(.brightness, to: 0.2)
color.change(.saturation, to: 0.3)
color.change(.alpha,      to: 0.4)

// chaining them returns a single new object with all values changed
color.change(.hue,        to: 0.5)
     .change(.brightness, to: 0.6)
     .change(.saturation, to: 0.7)
```

There are also options to apply **relative changes**:

```
// create a new UIColor object with hue & brightness increased by 0.2
color.change(.hue,        by: 0.2)
     .change(.brightness, by: 0.2)
```

The library also adds **some other handy UI features** into your project – checkout its README on GitHub for more details.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

One important note not yet mentioned here is that your UIColor should be in extended RGB space. Depending on how your color is originally created this function may return false if it's just RGB.

Secondly, I made a variant on @ambientlight's answer to make the API just a little more slick. You can adjust 1 or all properties.

```
extension UIColor {

    public func adjust(hueBy hue: CGFloat = 0, saturationBy saturation: CGFloat = 0, brightnessBy brightness: CGFloat = 0) -> UIColor {

        var currentHue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentSaturation: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentBrigthness: CGFloat = 0.0
        var currentAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        if getHue(&currentHue, saturation: &currentSaturation, brightness: &currentBrigthness, alpha: &currentAlpha) {
            return UIColor(hue: currentHue + hue,
                       saturation: currentSaturation + saturation,
                       brightness: currentBrigthness + brightness,
                       alpha: currentAlpha)
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method by setting the following values

`UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithHue: x.xx saturation: x.xx brightness: x.xx alpha: 1.0];`

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html

There is a class function with `colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:`

Of course you can first use `getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` before making any changes when you init with `[UIColor redColor]`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply modify this by

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:YourHueValue saturation:YourSaturationValue brightness:YourBrightnessValueValue alpha:1.00];
```

alpha denotes the opaqueness of view and it ranges from 0.0 - 1.0

Answer (score -1):

UIColor can't change the saturation/hue/brigthness,you can you CoreImage.

Some sample code below:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];

[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputContrast"];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] forKey:@"inputBrightness"];


[filter setValue:_A_CIImage_ forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

CIImage *_outputImage = filter.outputImage;

CIContext context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

CGImageRef outputImageRef = [context createCGImage: _outputImage fromRect:[_outputImage extent]];
```

Comment: colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: Creates and returns a color object using the specified opacity and HSB color space component values.   This method used for make a color with HSB color space , like RGB color space. Can't change a red color to other color.

Answer (score -1):

```
CGSize imageSize = [ba size];
CGRect imageExtent = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

// Create a context containing the image.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

[sourceimage drawInRect:imageExtent];
// Draw the hue on top of the image.
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
[[UIColor colorWithHue:yourvalue saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:1.0] set];
UIBezierPath *imagePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageExtent];
[imagePath fill];

CGImageRef imageref=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIImage *result =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageref];

CGImageRelease(imageref);
```

In the first two lines it describes image size and image rect. `CGContextRef` is used to create a context in core graphics. After that the 5th line is the image you want to apply hue and rect of image. After that blend mode which is important. After that UI `colorWithHue` in which values of hue, saturation, brightness and alpha are passed. To get a proper effect give 1.0 value of alpha. And at the end you should set `uicolor.create` bezerpath or you can directly give `cgcontextsetfill(context)`. At the end create `imageref` and put that image in `UIImage`. At the end, as always in choreographics, release `CGImageRelease` to hedge from memory issues.

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.

Comment: in first two line it describe image size and image rect. cgcontext is use to create a context in core graphics.after that 5th line is image uyou want to apply hue and rect of image .  after that blend mode which is important.after that ui colorWithHue in which pass value of hue ,saturation,brightness and alpha to get proper effect give 1.0 value of alpha.and at end set uicolor.create bezerpath or u can directly give cgcontextsetfill(context). At the end create imageref and put that image in uiimage .AT the end alway in choreographics release cgimageRef against memory issue.

Comment: It's always better to put relevant info inside the answer, as not everyone, if they have a similar problem, will dig into comments. Also, what did you mean by [choreographics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/choreographic)?

Answer (score -4):

```
[UIColor colorWithHue:0.10 saturation:0.16 brightness:0.13 alpha:1.00];
```

Comment: A simple line(s) of code is not considered a good answer. Please also explain why you did what and how this is helping.