# UINavigationBar setTranclucent not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UIViewController` where the `UINavigationBar` is pushing all the children views down. I have tried using this code in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewWillAppear` methods:

> self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

But this doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897485/achieving-bright-vivid-colors-for-an-ios-7-translucent-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `Extend Edges` property in the `Attributes inspector` also.

`Uncheck these (under top bars & under bottom bars )`

[image]