# iOS 7 NavigationBar not showing exact RGB color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I set a special color for my Nav Bar in the AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:(41.0f/255.0f) blue:(103.0f/255.0f) alpha:1]];
```

But the RGB Value which is then displayed is: R:12 G:48 B:110.
It seems that iOS just puts the values a bit higher. How can I avoid that? (Because it looks ugly)
And when I give the same color an customized TableViewSection it is right.

Screenshots:

NavBar:
[image: Navigation Bar]

Customized TableViewSection:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897485/achieving-bright-vivid-colors-for-an-ios-7-translucent-uinavigationbar?rq=1

Comment: No, I have the problem in the Tab Bar and both are not translucent

Comment: Try setting the opacity of the Nav bar to 1.0, because the white background may have an effect on the color.

Comment: TabBar has no property of opacity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok they were translucent. Unchecked translucent in StoryBoard, works fine now;)

Comment: If you're not using a storyboard, you can also set this programmatically using the `translucent` property of `UINavigationBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your AppDelegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem...i tried to replace expression in brackets (41.0f/255.0f) by value after divison (~0.1608)...and it works to me)