# Change the bar tint color makes the blurry area becomes black and white

Tags: ios, ios7, uitoolbar, blur

I would like to add a blurry effect on my view, and I used a `UIToolbar` to do that. But when I try to add bar tint color on the `UIToolbar`, something weird happens.

Here is the code I used to add `UIToolbar`, very basic, nothing fancy:

```
 UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.blurView.frame.size.width, self.blurView.frame.size.height)];
[self.blurView addSubview:toolbar];
```

Before I add the `barTintColor`, everything looks good:

[image]

But after I add bar tint color:

```
[toolbar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.000 alpha:0.500]];
```

Everything under the toolbar becomes black and white:

[image]

At first I thought something wrong with the color or the transparency, I've been playing with different color and different transparency. As long as I use `setBarTintColor`, it all becomes black and white like that. For example, a random bluish green:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to be an issue with UIToolbar.

Instead of setting the tint color, you can add a CALayer with a background color with an alpha component less than one, depending on how prominent you want your color to be, like so:

```
    CALayer *extraColorLayer = [CALayer layer];
    extraColorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, toolbar.frame.size.width, toolbar.frame.size.height);
    extraColorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255 green:g/255 blue:b/255 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    [toolbar.layer addSublayer:extraColorLayer];
```

This appears to create the effect you're looking for.

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18906759).

Answer (score -3):

I think it's better this case for black and white cases:

- iOS 7.0

  ```
  UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:self.blurView.bounds];
  if (isBlack)
      toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
  else
      toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
  toolbar.autoresizingMask = self.blurView.autoresizingMask;
  [self.blurView insertSubview:blurEffect atIndex:0];
  ```
- iOS 8.0 or latter

  ```
  UIBlurEffect *effect;
  if (isBlack)
      effect =[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
  else
      effect =[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

  UIVisualEffectView *blurEffect = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
  [self.blurView insertSubview:blurEffect atIndex:0];
  ```

You can create a class inherted of UIView and associate to the view that you need blur on Storyboard (on Custom Class)