# Translucent UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I'm having trouble making my UINavigationBar completely transparent with only the white text & buttons to be shown on it, so that the ImageView I use for ViewController background is completely visible at the top.

I've tried this code amongst other:

```
    // Set the BarTintColor to translucent and text colors to white
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

But [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbH67.jpg) is the result, a blackish UINavigationBar, **how can I solve this?**

The app pushes over from this [ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbH67.jpg) to this [ViewController](http://imgur.com/U5Jar6X) where the UINavigationBar fades over to red. There are several other ViewControllers doing the same fade animation, so the UINavigationBar is required

The part of the first ViewController with the "Ny" button will be improved;) - just working on getting my hands on a tool like Photoshop

Thanks!
Erik

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what I use to make the navigation bar transparent:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
self. navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: getting the same blackish UINavigationBar :/ @ShahabQureshi

Answer (score 0):

I have found this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897485/achieving-bright-vivid-colors-for-an-ios-7-translucent-uinavigationbar). 
Also with an example on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aprato/6631390)