# UINavigationBar Appearance not setting color correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I set the UINavigationBar color in the AppDelegate, the color does change, but it changes to a different shade of the color I specified.
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:globalColor];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming global color is in fact the color you think it is, also set

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

if you haven't already. Translucency can make the color appear different.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Is there a way that I can keep the color I want and still have a translucent effect??

Comment: @SalB. Eh... The problem is that when you make something translucent the background color kind of "mixes" in. But you can check out this answer for a good suggestion on how to potentially brighten up your colors even with transparency: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18906759/2274694

Comment: @SalB. Oh, and if it works for you, please select the checkmark near my answer to accept it.

Comment: Oh okay, and yeah I was trying to click the checkmark, but it said I had to wait 10 minutes, I forgot to :) But I did know.