# In iOS 7, how do I have a nav bar with a dark background color, but have it transparent and blurred?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

With my app and iOS 7, I want to have a green background for the navigation bar.

From what I see, I have two options: set the background color directly with a `UIColor` corresponding to green. This causes the green to be *very* washed out, but it does cause it to be transparent and blurred.

The other option I figured is to create a green background image that you manually set transparent yourself, then set this image as the nav's background image. This works 95%, but the background is *not* blurred. It does keep the right color and make it transparent however.

What is the correct way to do this? For instance, the new Facebook app for iOS 7 accomplishes this beautifully with their blue.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895252/get-the-right-color-in-ios7-translucent-navigation-bar/18917290#18917290

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you're looking for?

[image]

I did this using the bar's tint color:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.4f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Of course, you could also use a navigation bar instance directly instead of using the appearance proxy.

Comment: I meant more so something like this: http://i.imgur.com/uS9oTOM.png I find in that screenshot the color looks a little faded.