# ios Navigation bar tint color like facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, uinavigationbar, ios7

I need a navigation bar tint color like facebook's navigation bar(in iOS 7)

I picked the color of facebook App's  and set it by

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#365491"]];
```

But displaying wron color. The color is correct.I tested that color by setting it as a plain view's background.

Result of the above code is
[image]

But I need like this[image]

Also when I tried by setting a views background with same color is 
[image]

How can I reproduce  a navigation bar like facebook.

Comment: if your color not displayed proper then The best way is put image on navigationBar.. :)

Comment: tried by setting color with pattern image but nothing happened :(

Comment: use RGB code: R: 66 G: 94 B: 157... might be helpful;

Comment: make same background image and set navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer after a lot try

```
  if ([UINavigationBar instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarPosition:barMetrics:)]) {
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBGTile.png"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

  }
  else{
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:kBlueColorHex]];
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

In `iOS7`, the `UIColor` you set is not the same color that will be displayed on screen. Instead, `iOS` will adjust your `RGB` values a bit and use those as the color.

To calculate the color with white background behind the bar, you should use these formulas as explained in [Bar Color Calculator](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/bar-color-calculator-for-ios7) :

**Going from designs to `UIColor`:**

> (n – 102) / 0.6

**Going from `UIColor` to designs:**

> (255 – n) / 2.5 + n

*where n is the R, G or B 0-255 value.*

---

So, what you are getting using the `ColorPicker` or from some similar app is not the values you should use for R, G and B. But those are the values calculated by the iOS from some other RGB values. To get the exact value, you should follow these steps.

1. Get the values of R, G and B using ColorPicker for the Facebook Navigation Bar.
2. Use those values in above formulas to calculate the exact value.

   `For Eg: R_fromFB = (R – 102) / 0.6
         So, R = (0.6 * R_fromFB) + 102`
3. Use these R, G and B values in your Navigation Bar.

---

For Example, you can try with this color :

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(135/255.0) green:(153/255.0) blue:(189/255.0) alpha:1]
```

Comment: I noticed this log, But my RGB values are 54,84,145 
Author of this blog also said 

"Anything under 102 in this first equation will not work and will give a negative result. For this reason, only values of 102-255 in your designs will work."

Comment: @Johnykutty : Try to use 135,153 and 189 respectively for R, G and B.

Comment: @Vin what if I have colors: 0,57,72 ? it's below 102

Answer (score 1):

I made a special [BarTintColorOptimizer utility](https://github.com/IvanRublev/BarTintColorOptimizer) for optimizing translucent navigation bar tint color to make the bar's actual color to match the desired color in iOS 7.x and later.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900378/2924596) for Facebook color setting example.

Comment: And it still works with Xcode 8.2.1 and iOS 10. Brilliant work, saved me so much time. Kudos, Ivan!