# Navigation bar same bg color as view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiview

Our designer wants the navigation bar to have the same background color as the view's. However, they also want the navigation bar to remain translucent.

Obviously if I set it to non-translucent it works a treat:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];`

But that is not the desired effect. Is there a way I can make them the same color without spending hours tweaking the background color of the navigation bar?

This is what it looks like when we set the navigation and view to the same color:

[image]

Comment: am i missing something here? can you not set the colour to `[UIColor clearColor]`  ??

Comment: why? it needs to be transparent and the same colour .... whats the difference?

Comment: It still seems to ends up as a darker color due to the translucency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make UINavigationBar transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315862/make-uinavigationbar-transparent)

Comment: Nope, we do not want a transparent navigation bar.

Comment: Think I understand what you are trying to do and i've added an answer below. Let me know if its correct

Comment: The solution to your problem had been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19043174/3360360

Comment: @cjhill don't forgot to upvote and mark as top answer any answer that has solved your issue. If none have solved it, add a comment to them

Answer (score 2):

Just set empty image for background and shadow:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code    

 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor backgroundcolor]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Sentence #2 in the question clearly states, "However, they also want the navigation bar to remain translucent."

Answer (score 0):

Use this code hope it works

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:self.view.backgroundColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Answer (score -1):

I thinks the following piece of code would help you to achieve this.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.04 green:0.38 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0]];

     [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

you can also use color from RGB code or from hex.