# Transparent and tranculent tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've for quite some time been trying to create a transparent tab bar which i've seen in many apps(check the image at the bottom). However i cant seem to get the effect where it is transparent and blurry at the same time. So far i've just added a tab bar and set the transculent to true/yes depending on objective-c or swift. How can i achieve below tab bar?

[image]

Comment: RGB >= 40 will give you a good blur effect.

Comment: could u give example?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895252/get-the-right-color-in-ios7-translucent-navigation-bar

Comment: Did you come up with any solution? I am looking for the same thing