# make nav bar color same has uibutton swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicolor

I got this colour `UIColor(red:0.26, green:0.5, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0)`

When I applied it to uibutton and nav bar I like the nav bar color better than the original colour applied to the button . How do i get that color?
Here is pic

[image: pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your navigation bar is translucent, so its visible color is slightly lighter than the `tintColor`.
You can get rid of the translucency using :

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

But if you want to keep the translucent effect, for example if you use an `UIScrollView`, then i suggests you to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895252/get-the-right-color-in-ios7-translucent-navigation-bar). which provides a calculator to get the correct `tintColor`.

Comment: Yup, you got to it just before I did :D

Comment: I faced this issue with a black bar looking dark gray and remembered the solution ;)